# show message when devices connected wireless router

Tags: linux, windows, wireless-networking, smb2

I'm guessing the only way "Universally" to show a message like "Welcome to my WiFi connection" is through a html landing page( redirection). I would say SMB but I believe Windows 8 doesn't allow you to "push" messages like with Windows XP. I believe you can still send message via Windows computer to Windows computer via "msg" command, but this isn't very universal.

So my question is , with out 3rd party program installed on host computer, is their another way to push a message through when guest connects to your wireless connection?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a html landing page, I just wanted to see if there was a better way. With mobile you have push notifications,but I guess that's due to having the app that is sending the notifications installed.

Comment: The technical term is “captive portal”, by the way. You’ll probably have to use a different router firmware, though. I’m not aware of a consumer-grade router supporting this with the stock firmware.

Comment: @Daniel B there are a few, SOHO routers and a handful of discrete, consumer access points that offer this, although I can't think of any off the top of my head. DD-WRT, and maybe some of the other custom router firmware supports this as well.

Comment: If you were trying to go the MSG route, you would need a script to check the DHCP leases of your router, when a new lease is detected you would have it send a MSG /Server:$NEW-IP "Hi" but depending on your scripting abilities this might be more difficult to setup and users might have this blocked.

Comment: I'm using DD-Wrt. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest option to display messages to users connecting to your Wireless network will be through setting up a captive portal. You will redirect the users HTTP request, whatever it is and force them to go to a page of your choosing instead. Usually, they will have to stay on this page until they authenticate (login, click accept, etc). This will force every user to see your message.

The easiest way to setup a basic, Welcome to my Wifi, type message would be to purchase an Access Point or Router that has this ability built in. You can set this up manually, but that will be more involved. If you would like to go that route let us know and I can post some information to get you started.

Comment: Oh I understand this way. I'm just trying to think out of the box. Especially if I only want to show this captive portal once and base off the users wireless adapter Mac address and not browser cookies.